# How to control the Timeout for Enterprise WSDL for Salesforce integration

Tags: timeout, enterprise-wsdl

How to control the Timeout for Enterprise WSDL for Salesforce integration.

Answer (score 2):

The session of Enterprise WSDL is governed by Session Settings by your administrator .You can navigate to SetUp | Security Controls | Session Settings to set the timeout value

[image]

> The default is 120 minutes (two hours) and maximum values is 12hrs(Longer session time outs can be not safe depending on the business.)
>
> **If you make an API call, the inactivity timer is reset to zero.**

There are different mechanisms to prevent the session being timed out for API calls .

*Store the current time of the system + Time out time in a variable when a call is made and when next call is made compare the time with variable value to find if you need to make a login() call again .*

Below is an example code demonstration for that

```
  /**
  * This method is used to log in to salesforce and set the
  * private class variables for the wrapper, including the
   * session ID.
  */  

public void login() throws UnexpectedErrorFault, InvalidIdFault,
                       LoginFault, RemoteException, 
                       ServiceException {

resetBindingStub();
LoginResult loginResult = binding.login(username, password);
this.nextLoginTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 
                     (this.sessionlength * 60000);

this.binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.
                          ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                          loginResult.getServerUrl());
this.sessionId = loginResult.getSessionId();
this.serverUrl = loginResult.getServerUrl();

  // Create a new session header object and set the
  // session id to that returned by the login
 SessionHeader sh = new SessionHeader();
 sh.setSessionId(loginResult.getSessionId());
 this.binding.setHeader(new 
 SforceServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(),
   "SessionHeader", sh);
}
```

> Method to check Session is active or not

```
/**
* This method returns true if a login to Salesforce is
* necessary, otherwise false. It should be used to check the
* session length before performing any API calls.
*/  

private boolean loginRequired() {
    if (sessionId == null || sessionId.length() == 0) 
    return true;
  return !isConnected();
}

/**
* This method checks whether the session is active or not
* @return boolean
*/  

  public boolean isConnected() {
     return System.currentTimeMillis() < nextLoginTime;
  }
```

EDIT>>>

To set timeout values for each profile you can follow below

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_session.htm

Ask your admin to create a separate profile for integration where you can specify session time out

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the detailed explanation. My follow up question then is, this  session setting will then be effective throughout the entire org for all users, isn't it. Is there a way to control the timeout for the integration user only?

Comment: @DeepSinghal Just answered .You can create a separate profile and do session settings .Thanks

Comment: @DeepSinghal Why dont you mark the answer as answered so it helps others